# What is the difference between ReadConsole and fgets?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

What is the difference between `ReadConsole()` and `fgets()`? They seem to be able to read characters from `stdin`.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? There are many differences. For starters `ReadConsole` is a Windows specific function whereas `fgets` is a standard C function.

Comment: the big difference is that fgets is a c-runtime function that is portable, you can call that function in Linux or Windows for instance.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain more what you wish to accomplish, and we can recommend the correct function to use. BTW, `ReadConsole()` is quite a bit more limited about _where_ input comes from — it is a significantly lower-level function than `fgets()`.

Comment: For example, `fgets` can be used to read from anything that can be opened like a file. You may be surprised to read that you can use it on a mouse.

Comment: The results of their reading from the terminal seem to be the same (ReadConsole seems to include \r).When should I use ReadConsole?

Answer (score 0):

[ReadConsole function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole):Reads character input from the console input buffer and removes it from the buffer.

[fgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fgets-fgetws?view=msvc-160):Get a string from a stream.

**When should I use ReadConsole?**

According to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole#remarks):

> ReadConsole reads keyboard input from a console's input buffer. It
> behaves like the ReadFile function, except that it can read in either
> Unicode (wide-character) or ANSI mode. ReadConsole can only be used
> with a console input buffer handle, ReadFile can be used with other
> handles (such as files or pipes).

Comment: What function should I use to determine whether stdin is a console? isatty?

Answer (score 0):

These are different levels of programmation. `fgets` is a function from the C standard library, which means that it has to be present and behave the same in any C implementation. If you intend your code to be useable on other plaforms or simply are learning the C language, it should be your first choice.

`ReadConsole` is a function from Windows API. It cannot be used outside a Windows platform, but will exist in any of the Microsoft specific environments, from Visual Basic for Application (Microsoft Office macro system) to C#. If you are building a mixed language application targetting exclusively Windows, it can make sense to use it. Or if for any reason you want to be sure to access the console buffer and not a redirected standard input you *should* use that.

TL/DR: `fgets` is the standard C way. `ReadConsole` should only be used on Windows when you want to be sure to read the keyboard buffer and not a possible redirected standard input.